# discord.py let a user set a custom welcome command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

im trying to let users set a custom welcome command, eg by running /welcomesetup they are prompted to enter a message which users will be later welcomed with (im wanting to have server owners set this up in their own servers and was also wondering if only one user would be able to set it up since its almost hardcodes, would i need a database of some sort on server IDS and each induvidual welcome message which can also be set up VIA the bot or not, and if so how would i go about this)

I created a prompt which is then stored as a varible for a user, however when testing the function it didnt work.

My code is bellow:

```
@bot.slash_command(
    guild_ids=[config["guild_id"]],
    name="welcomesetup",
    description="Setup a welcome message.",
)
async def welcomesetup(ctx):
        welcmessage = await prompt(ctx, "Message For welcome:")
        
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send(f"{newwelcome}")
```

VSC says

> NameError: name 'newwelcome' is not defined

Thank you for any asnwers!

Comment: Are you defining `newwelcome` anywhere? The error says exactly what it means.

Comment: Yeah cant edit it but its the same error even if "newwelcome" is set where "welcmessage is"

Comment: Yes because that's how scoping works, any variable declared in `welcomesetup` isn't visible outside of it...

Answer (score 0):

As MrDiamond pointed out in the comments; the error is because `newwelcome` isn't defined within the `on_member_join` function. Setting `newwelcome` in `welcomesetup` won't work either - as the variable is only available in that local scope.

One place to start would be:

```py
DEFAULT_WELCOME = "Welcome!"
# create a dict that we'll use for storing welcome messages for each guild
welcome_messages = {}

@bot.slash_command(
    guild_ids=[config["guild_id"]],
    name="welcomesetup",
    description="Setup a welcome message.",
)
async def welcomesetup(ctx, message: str):
    # set message in our data structure
    welcome_messages[ctx.guild.id] = message
    # you should probably send a message here to the user letting them know that you've done as they requested
    await ctx.respond(content="Saved your welcome message", ephemeral=True)


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    # get the welcome message from the dict
    # use the 'default' in case it's not been set
    welcome = welcome_messages.get(member.guild.id, DEFAULT_MESSAGE)
    await member.send(welcome)
```

This is a basic example but here's some other considerations to have going forward:

- what if a guild wants multiple options for welcome messages but one picked randomly?
- when my bot is restarted, all the welcome messages are lost
- what if the user doesn't allow messages from unknown users, then `await member.send` will throw an error

For the latter, you could look at storing the information in a file. Or perhaps look at using a form of database for storing the data.

Comment: How would i go about storing guild IDS and unique welcome messages in a text file? Can you help with that too, thank you for your previous answer also!!

Comment: I can't edit my answer due to too many pending edits; it's not too difficult to figure out via googling/other stack overflow answers. I might come back and edit this later when the queue dies down though.

Comment: I added your code and it said "Application Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'welcome_messages' is not defined"

Comment: Is everything in the same file or is it spread across different bits? Which bit of the code failed?

Comment: @Lethal consider using an actual database instead of a text file

Comment: Yes as @stijndcl says, a database would be superior to using a file anyways.

Comment: Im a monkey idk how to do tha ennit, also its all in one file my program